# NextJS, Apollo, WPGraphQL & Combining or Retrieving more than 100 Records

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, wp-graphql

I am trying to retrieve more than 100 records for a WPGraphQL query using Apollo during getStaticProps. The wonderful WPGraphQL maker, Jason, pointed me towards using the pagination method and then combining the results into one new Array (or Object?).

The issue i'm having though is...well I can't get it to combine or really do anything more than getting one query. In my getStaticProps I have one query which retrieves only 100 records &  works, but if I try to add another one it doesn't work, and I get a error on the data saying it doesn't exist (even though I know it exists...):

```
Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'campgrounds' of undefined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

pages/camps.js (355:11) @ getStaticProps

  353 |   });
  354 | 
> 355 |   dataset2.campgrounds.edges.map((city) => {
      |           ^
  356 |     return cities.push({
  357 |       city: city.node.acfDetails.city,
  358 |     });
```

So i'm unsure what to do and hoping you folks can help. I'm sure i'm just missing something stupid or doing something stupid.

Ultimately I am trying to effectively just retrieve ~156 records from the database ***without pagination***, which I guess the best way to do it is to split it into two queries and then combine the data. Thank you so much for any help.

Here's my getStaticProps code that doesn't work:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query allCamps {
        features(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            label: name
            value: name
          }
        }
        regions(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            name
            regioncoord {
              latitude
              longitude
            }
          }
        }
        ownerships(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
        campgrounds(first: 200) {
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              acfDetails {
                additionalNotes
                address
                city
                closeDate
                description
                eMailAddress
                fieldGroupName
                latitude
                longitude
                maxAmps
                maximumRvLength
                numberOfSites
                openDate
                phoneNumber
                picture {
                  altText
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
                state
                website
                zipCode
              }
              id
              title
              features {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              regions {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              ownerships {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              title
              uri
              id
              link
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  const {dataset2} = await client.query({
    query: gql`
     query allCamps($endcursor: String) {
      features(first: 300) {
        nodes {
          label: name
          value: name
        }
      }
      regions(first: 300) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          regioncoord {
            latitude
            longitude
          }
        }
      }
      ownerships(first: 300) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
      campgrounds(first: 100, after: $endcursor) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
          hasPreviousPage
          startCursor
        }
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            acfDetails {
              additionalNotes
              address
              city
              closeDate
              description
              eMailAddress
              fieldGroupName
              latitude
              longitude
              maxAmps
              maximumRvLength
              numberOfSites
              openDate
              phoneNumber
              picture {
                altText
                mediaItemUrl
              }
              state
              website
              zipCode
            }
            id
            title
            features {
              nodes {
                name
              }
            }
            regions {
              nodes {
                name
              }
            }
            ownerships {
              nodes {
                name
              }
            }
            title
            uri
            id
            link
          }
        }
      }
    }`, variables: {endcursor: data.campgrounds.pageInfo.endCursor}
  })

  const { features } = data;
  const cities = [];

  data.campgrounds.edges.map((city) => {
    return cities.push({
      city: city.node.acfDetails.city,
    });
  });

  dataset2.campgrounds.edges.map((city) => {
    return cities.push({
      city: city.node.acfDetails.city,
    })
  })

  const object = [];

  features.nodes.map((feature) => {
    return object.push({
      label: feature.label,
      value: feature.label,
    });
  });

  return {
    props: {
      allCampInfo: data,
      regions: data.regions,
      camptypes: data.ownerships,
      object,
      graphCampgrounds: data.campgrounds.edges,
      cities,
      endCursor: data.campgrounds.pageInfo.endCursor,
    },
  };
}
```

And here's the code with just one query that does work:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query allCamps {
        features(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            label: name
            value: name
          }
        }
        regions(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            name
            regioncoord {
              latitude
              longitude
            }
          }
        }
        ownerships(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
        campgrounds(first: 200) {
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              acfDetails {
                additionalNotes
                address
                city
                closeDate
                description
                eMailAddress
                fieldGroupName
                latitude
                longitude
                maxAmps
                maximumRvLength
                numberOfSites
                openDate
                phoneNumber
                picture {
                  altText
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
                state
                website
                zipCode
              }
              id
              title
              features {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              regions {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              ownerships {
                nodes {
                  name
                }
              }
              title
              uri
              id
              link
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  const { features } = data;
  const cities = [];

  data.campgrounds.edges.map((city) => {
    return cities.push({
      city: city.node.acfDetails.city,
    });
  });

  const object = [];

  features.nodes.map((feature) => {
    return object.push({
      label: feature.label,
      value: feature.label,
    });
  });

  return {
    props: {
      allCampInfo: data,
      regions: data.regions,
      camptypes: data.ownerships,
      object,
      graphCampgrounds: data.campgrounds.edges,
      cities,
      endCursor: data.campgrounds.pageInfo.endCursor,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are extracting the data in your second query seems to be incorrect. You need to extract `data` again. But you can alias it like so:

```
const {data: dataset2} = await client.query({
```

There is no `dataset2` key in the returned object of the query, that is why you get a `null` value for `dataset2`.